# How to filter FireDAC dataset by a DATE value constant?

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with qryWithFilter do
  begin
    Filtered := False;
    OnFilterRecord := nil;
    // date separator may be used any from [' ', '-', '\', '.', '/']
    // Filter := 'DATA_NAS < (''DatetoStr(date3)'')';
    // Filter := 'DATA_NAS < ''28/06/1939''';
    // Filter := 'DATA_NAS < (FormatDateTime(''dd/mm/yyyy'', ''28/06/1968''))';
    // Filter := 'DATA_NAS < TO_DATE(''1996-07-29'',''yyyy-mm-dd'')';
    Filter := 'DATA_NAS < (TO_DATE(''1996-07-29'',''yyyy-mm-dd''))';
    Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

Only work with ''28/06/1968''. The error I'm getting is:

[image]

How can I filter my FireDAC query by a DATE value constant?

Answer (score 2):

The FireDAC's [**Filter**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) property implementation doesn't support DBMS functions, but   offers you their own expression engine.

With FireDAC converting a string constant into a [**DATE**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-date) type value in the [**Filter**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) property expression can be as simple as using the [**CONVERT**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Convert_Macro_Function_(FireDAC)) macro function or [**{d}**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences) escape sequence. The expression engine then picks a DBMS specific conversion function for you.

Try one of these filters (date string format for all variants is **yyyy-mm-dd**):

```pascal
uses
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with FDQuery do
  begin
    { disable filter }
    Filtered := False;
    { filter with date escape sequence (is nicely readable) }
    Filter := 'DATA_NAS < {d 1996-07-29}';
    { filter with CONVERT macro function without function escape sequence }
    Filter := 'DATA_NAS < {CONVERT(''1996-07-29'', DATE)}';
    { filter with CONVERT macro function with function escape sequence }
    Filter := 'DATA_NAS < {fn CONVERT(''1996-07-29'', DATE)}';
    { enable filter }
    Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Aren't FireDAC's escape sequences useful for producing RDBMS-independent SQL only? Filters are processed by FireDAC itself, they shouldn't need such "independent approach". I think there should be a native format for writing dates such that filter understads them (but I don't know which).